# padding change size of inner element which has applied flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need to set up the padding for a div element `menu` but I want to keep its size to 10% of its container.

As you can see from my example, the `menu` goes over the wrapper.

I would like to know how to fix it, keeping `menu` at 100% (I can use calc) and why the problem in first place. Thanks.

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: red;
}

#menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: orange;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left:75px; // problem here
}
.item {
    width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
    background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="menu">
    <div class="item">a
    </div>
    <div class="item">a
    </div>
    <div class="item">a
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can add the `box-sizing`property.

The default is `content-box` which only includes an element's `width` and `height`. `border-box` also includes `padding` and `border` properties.

[More information from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

Explanation for the way I've included it in the snippet [here](https://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/).

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: red;
}

#menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: orange;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left:75px; // problem here
}
.item {
    width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
    background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="menu">
    <div class="item">a
    </div>
    <div class="item">a
    </div>
    <div class="item">a
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```